# Need Regex match() to split numeric character and numbers and string along with special character

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use Regex `match()` to split numbers and string along with special character in jQuery?

For example:

```
str = "+10días" // this is my the string. (number + string along with any special character)

string = str.match("needed stuf");
```

I need like this so that `string[0] = 10` and `string[1] = "días"`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is the format always the same? Ie. a `+`, then 2 digits, then 4 letters

Comment: no its not in same format, that's my problem. even its contain only numeric or numeric and only one character and so on.

Comment: Please refer the below link. i used like this in link but i did't get answer as i expect. var str = "+10días"; 
    var res = str.match(/(-?\d*\.*\d+|[A-z]+)/g);

Comment: Use `str.match(/(\d+)(\D+)/)`

Comment: hi mohammad, i tried you answer, i got result very close to my requirmnet, (Ans: 10días,10,días), but it i don't need the first one, i need only second and third one. any suggesion plz.

Comment: Use string[1] and string[2], to get the groups, ignore first match (on first index of array of matches)?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var str = "+10días"

var parts= str.match(/[^0-9]+|[0-9]+/g)
```

Comment: hi crazy, thanks for your answer, but the special character in my string is not  only "í" it contain any special character .  can you please suggest it works for any special character as per my requirment.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = "+10días"
            var arr = new Array();
            str = str.replace(str.match(/[^\w\*]/), '')
            arr.push(str.match(/^[0-9]+/g)[0])
            str = str.replace(str.match(/^[0-9]+/g)[0], '')
            arr.push(str)
            console.log(arr)
        });
    </script>

</head>
</html>
```